# Is it possible to use CONCAT_WS add separator only if value not empty

Tags: php, mysql, concat-ws

Let say I have this table

```
id  a       b
1   data    1234
2   data
```

I want to concat with separator (but) if no data, don't add the separator.

If I do

```
UPDATE `table` SET `b` = CONCAT_WS(',',`b`,'newData') WHERE `id` = '1'
```

I get the expected 1234,newData in `b`

but I I do

```
UPDATE `table` SET `b` = CONCAT_WS(',',`b`,'newData') WHERE `id` = '2'
```

I get ,newData in `b` (( but I want only newData without the separator )).

IS there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one Mate:

```
# [A] sample result set for checking
SELECT 
    `a`, `b`,
    IF(
        (`a` IS NOT NULL AND `a` != '')
        AND (`b` IS NOT NULL AND `b` != ''),
        CONCAT_WS(',', `a`, `b`),
        REPLACE(CONCAT_WS(',', `a`, `b`), ',', '')
    ) `result`
FROM `table`
WHERE `id` IN (1, 2);
```

If the result set in `[A]` satisfied what you need, you can proceed with the script using `[B]`

---

The Update query:

```
# [B] process query for the new values
UPDATE `table`
SET `b` = IF(
    (`a` IS NOT NULL AND `a` != '')
    AND (`b` IS NOT NULL AND `b` != ''),
    CONCAT_WS(',', `a`, `b`),
    REPLACE(CONCAT_WS(',', `a`, `b`), ',', '')
)
WHERE `id` IN (1, 2);
```

Hope I can help, cheers!